# Why does this loop return a value that's O(n log log n) and not O(n log n)?

Tags: loops, for-loop, time-complexity, nested-loops, asymptotic-complexity

Consider the following C function:

```
int fun1 (int n)
{
    int i, j, k, p, q = 0;

    for (i = 1; i<n; ++i)
    {
        p = 0;

        for (j=n; j>1; j=j/2)
            ++p;

        for (k=1; k<p; k=k*2)
            ++q;
    }
    return q;
}
```

The question is to decide which of the following most closely approximates the return value of the function `fun1`?

(A) n^3
(B) n (logn)^2
(C) nlogn
(D) nlog(logn)

This was the explanation which was given :

```
int fun1 (int n)
{
    int i, j, k, p, q = 0;

    // This loop runs T(n) time 

    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        p = 0;

        // This loop runs T(Log Log n) time
        for (j=n; j > 1; j=j/2)
            ++p;

        // This loop runs T(Log Log n) time
        for (k=1; k < p; k=k*2)
            ++q;

    }
    return q;
}
```

But Time Complexity of a loop is considered as O(Logn) if the loop variables is divided / multiplied by a constant amount.

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i *= c) {
    // some O(1) expressions
}

for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= c) {
    // some O(1) expressions
}
```

But it was mentioned that the inner loops take Θ(Log Log n) time each , can anyone explain me the reason ar is the answer wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is tricky - there is a difference between what the *runtime* of the code is and what the *return value* is.

The first loop's runtime is indeed O(log n), not O(log log n). I've reprinted it here:

```
p = 0;
for (j=n; j > 1; j=j/2)
  ++p;
```

On each iteration, the value of j drops by a factor of two. This means that the number of steps required for this loop to terminate is given by the minimum value of k such that n / 2<sup>k</sup> ≤ 1. Solving, we see that k = O(log<sub>2</sub> n).

Notice that each iteration of this loop increases the value of p by one. This means that at the end of the loop, the value of p is Θ(log n). Consequently, this next loop does indeed run in time O(log log n):

for (k=1; k < p; k=k*2)
      ++q;
   }

The reason for this is that, using similar reasoning to the previous section, the runtime of this loop is Θ(log p), and since p = Θ(log n), this ends up being Θ(log log n).

However, the question is **not** asking what the runtime is. It's asking what the **return value** is. On each iteration, the value of q, which is what's ultimately returned, increases by Θ(log log n) because it's increased once per iteration of a loop that runs in time Θ(log log n). This means that the net value of q is Θ(n log log n). Therefore, although the algorithm **runs in time O(n log n)**, it **returns a value that's O(n log log n)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @coder101 To the best of my knowledge, the claim that the time complexity is O(n log log n) is incorrect. Notice that the question does *not* ask how long the function takes to return, but rather asks for what you can say about the return value (q).

Comment: Yes that was very helpful , their answer is right but the explaination is wrong :)

Comment: Dude can you please check this question too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811753/asymptotic-complexity-for-typical-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Answer would be (D) O(n * log(log n)). The reason is described below :-

The first for loop encompasses other 2 for loops which are based on the values of j and k respectively. Also, j is getting halved from n, until it is greater than 1. So, p will be equal to greatest integer(log n). And, k is doubling till it equals p --- where p has been set from previous loop and would be equal to [log n], where [x] is equal to greatest integer of x.

So, the third loop will run for log (log n) time, so value of q will be `log (log n)`. And, hence, both the inner loops being part of the outer for-loop which runs for n times.

Approximate value of q = n* log (log n)) = O(n log(log n)) .

Comment: Reread the question carefully - it's asking what the *return value* is rather than the runtime. I made the same mistake the first time around.

Comment: @templatetypedef-Added the answer, but, probably I am too late. :(

Comment: It is for trying to help me :)

Comment: @coder101-Oh, I thought templatetypedef upvoted. Anyways, THANKS. :)

Comment: Dude can you please check this question too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811753/asymptotic-complexity-for-typical-expressions

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong i see here concerns the second loop:
    for (j=n; j>1; j=j/2) 
You say in comments : *This loop runs Θ(Log Log n) time*

As I see it, this loop runs O(Log n) times

The running times for the first and third loops are correct (O(n) and O(Log Log n)).

EDIT: I agree with the previous answer. I did not notice that the question is about the return value, not the running time!

Comment: Dude can you please check this question too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30811753/asymptotic-complexity-for-typical-expressions